# why a user who have been assigned "Basic User" role on a production environment can not see the environment

Tags: power-automate, administration, powerapp, power-platform, dataverse

I have created a new Environment of type production + which have a data verse data source. Then i went to Security role >> add a test user to the "Basic User" role as follow: -

[image: johnjohn123_0-1683803148056.png]

and when I checked the user's permission on the environment using the "app access checker", i got this result:-

[image: johnjohn123_3-1683803408485.png]

but for more than 1 hour >> the test user cannot see the above production environment >> where the user can only see the default environment, as follow: -

[image]

so what could be the reason? now the user is a test user i am using to test permissions , and has those licenses:-

[image: johnjohn123_2-1683803288251.png]

any advice why the user can not see the environment?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I waited for more than 2 hours to show up the environment for new user. In my case, user is having Power Apps Plan 2 Trial and M365 E3 license.

Comment: @GaneshSanap how those staff works is really confusing,, so could the reason be that the user does not have E license ?

Comment: @GaneshSanap i mean my test user does not have any E-type licesne